# Get data from Joomla jos_users table

Tags: php, oop, joomla, field

I'm trying to build a little bit advanced users system using Joomla, but I stuck at one spot.

I added new field on Joomla's jos_users table, but when I wanted to get that field out, like "echo" - it didn't worked at all. Any other data, even password field I can get without problems.

Of course, I added new value in /var/www/<project>/libraries/joomla/user/user.php like this after line 40.

```
/**
* The users address name
* @var string
*/
var $address            = null;
```

What might be the problem here? Or what I did wrong, or what I didn't do at all?

Thanks for replies!

Cheerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make the necessary changes in /libraries/joomla/database/table/user.php ?

You also need to make changes in this file for your another field.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned methods will sure work but the problem here is you're modifying the core files ... further updates might make changes to the mentioned files then you'll have to modify the new files again.

In my opinion you could use an extension like [Community Builder](http://www.joomlapolis.com/) or other similar extension on this [group](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities) and your website will be update proof ... any future updates will never make your registeration break.

Answer (score 0):

You also missed the JTableUser class at /libraries/joomla/database/table/user.php

However the best practice here would be to create additional table linked to #_*user table. I.e. #*_mycomponentUsers: userid, address, birthday, pets_name, whatever
userid would be the primary index, and contain the id of corresponding user in #__users.

Think big: you'll want to add more fields at some point, and a security risk will be found and fixed in the next Joomla release.